# Automating the Conversion of Tasks to Sub-Tasks and Moving Them to a Specific Story in Jira

Tags: jira, confluence

I am utilizing a Jira Issue Collector where users can submit issues as tasks. Once a task is created on the board, I aim to automate the following process:

1. Convert the newly created task into a sub-task.
2. Move this sub-task under a specific story on the board.

I'm seeking a way to create an automation rule in Jira to accomplish this. The objective is to have the sub-task automatically become part of a predetermined story once it's created via the Issue Collector. Any guidance on setting up such an automation rule or suggestions for plugins or scripts to achieve this would be highly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for any help provided!

I tried to play around the automation rules and additional fields.